# Angular2 trackBy optimisation

Tags: angular, dom

How does trackBy work internally ?

I mean does it rely on id property of ElementRef.nativeElement to get/set information ?

(Because if not, what would be the purpose of the id attribute in ElementRef.nativeElement ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular by default checks object identity

```
<div *ngFor="let item in items">
```

in this case of `item`

With `trackBy` you can instruct it to track by index or by a property of `item`.

`trackBy` allows to specify a function (that returns a value for an item passed to it). Angular calls this function and uses the returned value for comparison instead of the object identity it uses by default

`trackBy` is not in any way related to properties of `nativeElement`.

> what would be the purpose of the id attribute in ElementRef.nativeElement

The `id` attribute can be used to reference an HTML element from CSS, `querySelector`, `<label for="someId">` and others. This is not specific to Angular and I don't know anything Angular-specific that requires or expects the `id` attribute to be present.

Comment: He is asking "how does the trackby works internally to determine which HTML element is related to x javascript object?" I don't think your answer is appropriate unless I misunderstood.

Comment: Yes, and in the meantime, this "id", should I have to use ElementRef to set it ?

Comment: @Ploppy trackBy is just a function that returns a value for an item passed to it. Angular calls this function and uses the returned value for comparison instead of the object identity it uses by default.

Comment: @Stef it's not releted to `ElementRef` neither. It's only related to the value (`item` in my example).